# Why are the measurements different in the Properties > Transform palettes in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I don’t even really understand the difference between the two panels. The second one puts the Y coord at .75" (correct), and the first one says it’s at 0. I also occasionally notice that the widths and heights are different—not just rounded—and the second panel will be labeled “Rectangle.” Can someone please explain what’s going on here?

Comment: Must be a CC2018 Thing.. no AI Properties Panel in CC2017.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I suspect a glitch with your file - I can't duplicate this - in my file, the two palettes show corresponding data.

[image]

And when clicking on the "more here" ellipsis in the palette corner - more of the same - corresponding data.

[image]

I think I'm going to suggest copying elements out a layer at a time into a brand new `.ai` file.

Comment: Is it the same if you click on the three dots at the bottom right of the Properties > Transform palette? Not the tearaway one?

Comment: Let me see if I can reliably reproduce. I’ve seen this happen in a few different files.

Comment: it would be perfect for us if you find out how to trigger it :D

Answer (score 0):

The properties panel sometimes doesn’t update for certain properties (e.g if you change the units from in to px for artboard from ruler, it won’t update unless you deselect the artboard and then re select it) maybe that’s the case.

Comment: or maybe whole preferences got corrupt ; or maybe his illustrator misbehaving :D :D  since even me too failed in reproducing the error

Comment: There are two places where the properties are updated. 1) properties pallets 2) properties panel on the right side of screen. Change the artboard units and you’ll see the difference.